# Excel: getting cells content to generate Google maps Url

Tags: excel, google-maps

I have followed this tutorial:

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Xnp2B0JBD_Y&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DXnp2B0JBD_Y

and now I have a google map in my excel stylesheet with a formula like this:

="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="&B1&"&addr="&B2&"&daddr="B3""

B1 contains Madrid
B2 contains Barcelona
B3 contains Sevilla

It plots ok the markers in the map.

Now I would like to select the cells with the mouse (B1, B8, B14, B17...or from B1 to B25) and generate the formula. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input prompt and then concatenate the response.  Here is how to get a range from a user:

```
On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set rRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
            "Please select cells with your mouse.", _
                Title:="SPECIFY RANGE", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    If rRange Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

URL = "http://maps.google.com/maps?s"

For Each cell In rRange
   URL = URL & "addr=""&" & cell.Address & "&""&"
Next

URL = Left(URL, Len(URL) - 1)

Range("C1").FormulaLocal = URL
```

Output in C1 looks like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="&$B$1&"&addr="&$B$2&"&addr="&$B$3&"
```

Comment: I've updated the last part of the code to string together your addresses better.